# CASE statement equivalent to if or else-if

Tags: sql, case, netezza

In this sql CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN col1 = 'X' then 'A'  
CASE when col2 = 'Y' then 'B'  
else 'C' as result ...
```

if col1=X, and col2 = Y, will the output be 'A' or 'B' ? i.e. is the CASE statement functioning as an if or an else-if?

Comment: it functions like if, else-if, else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The evaluation of cases will terminate on the first one that evaluates to TRUE.